# There's a bunch of wierd tags, can they be cleaned up?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The [ip](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip) tag seems to be a synonym of [ip-address](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip-address), though it could also stand for intellectual property.

[address](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address) also is a synonym of one of the above.

The [recommendations](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) tag looks like it should be blacklisted, it's really ambiguous and could mean a lot of things.

[clean-urls](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clean-urls) looks like it means [url-rewriting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url-rewriting)

[seo-friendly](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo-friendly) looks like it means making sure that google can read your site, but they way it's being used, it's like a synonym of [seo](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo).

What does the [search](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) tag mean? I think that this should also be blacklisted.

Same with [web-applications](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-applications) [dynamic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) [hacking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacking) and [tools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools)

Could [tags](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) be renamed to `html-tags`, just so it's clearer that it's referring to html tags?

Is there a difference between [meta](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta) and [metadata](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metadata)?

Those were all the things that I found, but there are probably more. Can someone (a moderator) take care of them?

Comment: I'll take care of these soon. Some of these are not cut and dry but I'll make sense of the ones I can.

Comment: @JohnConde awesome. I just found the address tag (http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address), which is a synonym of `ip` or `ip-address`

Answer (score 1):

- I made [seo-friendly](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo-friendly) a synonym of [seo](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo)
- I created a new tag, [meta-tags](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags), and made [meta](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta) and [metadata](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metadata) synonyms of it. I had to verify that each question-asker what meant by meta and metadata was meta tags related and that was the case in every question they were tagged so this seemed like the right thing to do.
- [tags](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) could also mean tagging as commonly used in Wordpress so I did not make any changes there (The definition of this tag needs to be updated appropriately)
- [search](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) [web-applications](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-applications) [dynamic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) [hacking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacking) and [tools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) are IMHO worth keeping even they don't offer a tremendous amount of value. [web](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web) and [website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website) probably should be deleted as they are unnecessary IMHO.
- I created a new tag [intellectual-property](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intellectual-property) as one question marked [ip](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip) was about that and not IP addresses. I then made [ip](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip) a synonym of [ip-addresses](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip-addresses).
- [address](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address) is a tough one. It could mean web address, street address, or IP address. I left it alone for now since it's better to have it exist and be vague then not be available at all.
- [recommendations](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) is useful as it is a good indicator a site is subjective and probably should be closed.
- To me [clean-urls](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clean-urls) is a noun and [url-rewriting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url-rewriting) verb so technically they are different things.

Comment: I disagree about the recommendation tag. New users could see that tag, and think that recommendations are on topic.

Comment: The definition probably should include a notice that recommendations are off-topic. In addtion, any tag that has a canonical question (CMS, looking for hosting, etc) should also point to the canonical question in its definition.

Comment: If recommendations are off-topic, then shouldn't looking-for-a-script be off-topic too. And, I don't think a notice will help, new users who see the tag will think those questions are on-topic, and will ask questions. Here's a perfect example of that: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30714/which-directory-script-can-i-use-to-build-a-similar-site-to-this-one#comment29779_30714

Comment: And, why are search, web-applications, dynamic, hacking and tools worth keeping? They seem really worthless to me.

Comment: No matter what we do there will be users who ask low quality, stupid, and/or off-topic questions here. The best we can do is provide an environment which does it best to deter this and let the community moderation handle the rest.

Comment: OK, good point. I'm retagging a lot of the `tags` questions, a lot of them are refering to html or meta tags. I'll then update the description so that it refers to wordpress tags

Comment: Also, I found `seo-audit`, which should be a dup of `seo` IMHO